# Escaping text so it would remain readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, xss

I have a method which looks like this

```
def full
 "#{self.first} #{self.second}"
end
```

problem is that I want to escape it, so to do it in the model I do

```
def full
 ERB::Util.h("#{self.first} #{self.second}")
end
```

but if `first` or `second` have `&` in it, it would give me `&amp;` instead of `&`
also if they have apostrphies `'` it would escape them and make it unreadable..

Is there a way to avoid XSS and make the string readable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this `html_escape` [Click here...](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape)

Comment: removing `ERB::Util.h`.....let's assume that `self.first = String1 &` and `self.second = String2`...  will result like this: 
`"String1 & String2" #=> result is String1 & String2..`
`ERB::Util.h("String1 & String2) # => result is String1 &amp; String2`